# How to make two server communicate each other asynchronously

Tags: node.js, api, asynchronous

Suppose I have two servers. First server makes a post request to the second server. The body of the request object contains the important raw data. We take this data as input into the second server and process it to generate new data which is uploaded to some system like AWS S3. After that, we send this download link to the first server by making a request there.

Now, this processing of data takes some time(few minutes) and we don't want to make the first server wait for that duration. So I want to immediately send a response to the first server that I have received its request and its output will soon be sent to it. Now I am wondering what would be the best approach to solve this problem.

Here is some code

Second Server

```
app.post('/data', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Processing started. Will send data soon');
  doProcessing(req.body, function(processedData) {  // this function takes time to complete
    console.log('Work Completed');
    request.send(url, processedData); // send the processed data back to the first server
  });
});
```

Now, this code is not working because of the asynchronous nature of nodejs. The doProcessing function is not executed completely. It interrupts in between. What are the approaches we can use here. Please Help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should read about Socket.io. When you receive response from second server you just do `socket.emit` and on client side `socket.on`. You just need to pass socket identifier from first server to second one and send it back in response from second -> first (you need to know where to send it)

You also can create simple Ajax request in loop asking server if action is ready. Just ask server every 2-5 seconds about that link and update DOM.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think you didn't get the question completely. I am sorry about my description. Here, two servers are communicating between each other. There are no clients. First Server is making a request to second server. The second server process data of the request object but it takes some time So I want to immediately acknowledge the request by sending a response back to first server and send the processed data after some time. The first server is in flask and the second server is in nodejs.

Comment: Ok. You are doing request from second server to first one? So whats wrong with it? It should work in my opinion.

Comment: Nah, the `socket` stuff is fine. The problem is making the second request containing link back to the first server. Since I have already sent an `acknowledgment` response back to the first server, the function `doProcessing` is not able to execute completely and interrupts in between since we go out of the `route callback` in the second server. We are not able to make a second request. This is the main problem.

Comment: Yo cant send response twice.. You need to call some kind of endpoint in first server. I thought that this request is https://github.com/request/request library. And ```url``` is something like http://firstserver/processingdone . I would do it like that.